# I am trying to get the correct font size for my subform in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am using Access 2016, and here is my form and subform:

[image]

I would like to increase the font of my subform's fields (i.e. Clinical observations, reportedBy,...) but can't seem to do so. Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: If you open the subform directly (in datasheet view), you should be able to set the font size. Then save the form.

Comment: Hi Andre! Thank you for your answer. I tried: the font does increase, but it still remains the same on the form. :/

Comment: Is the source object of your subform a form in datasheet view, or a table or query?

Comment: try layoutview and select the subform and increase the font size

Comment: @Andre, Krish KM Thank you very much! It worked great! So simple! :/